# mouseover nav link does not work

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I want to addEventListioner on the nav element `<a>`, but it didn't work. And I don't like solve it by way of jQuery. My code is as below:

```
<div id="navigation">
   <nav class="navbg clearfix">
    <a class="navcell" href="#">item1</a>
        <a class="navcell" href="#">item2</a>
        <a class="navcell" href="#">item3</a>
        <a class="navcell" href="#">item4</a>
        <a class="navcell" href="#">item5</a>
        <a class="navcell" href="#">item6</a>
   </nav>
</div>
```

And JS is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var navobj = document.getElementById("navigation").getElementsByTagName("a");
   for(var i=0; i < navobj.length; i++){
      navobj[i].onmouseover = function(){
          DD_belatedPNG.fix('.selected');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not properly closed, you are missing one `'}'`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var navobj = document.getElementById("navigation").getElementsByTagName("a");
   for(var i=0; i < navobj.length; i++){
      navobj[i].onmouseover = function(){
          DD_belatedPNG.fix('.selected');
       };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var navobj = document.getElementById("navigation").getElementsByTagName("a");
     for(var i=0; i < navobj.length; i++){
      navobj[i].onmouseover = function(){
          DD_belatedPNG.fix('.selected');
      }  //you have missed this closing bracket.
    }
</script>
```

You have missed a closing curly bracket.